# Can you save docker state so you dont have to pull services again?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run `docker-compose up -d`, the docker file downloads the services to run.

Is there a way to save that state, so that if I were to transfer the file to another computer, I could run the container without having to redownload (pull) the services again?

Answer (score 1):

If on your local machine you have the same images specified in your compose, then it will start building them. Say you have a `db` and `ruby` services in your compose:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:11-alpine'
 ...
 ...
  web:
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.dockerfile
```

**.dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6-alpine
...
```

then, if locally there are `postgres:11-alpine` and `ruby:2.6.6-alpine` it will build them, otherwise it will download any missing image.
If you have a volume to store your data, you could export it too and not losing anything.